# Java Scanner hasNextLine NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java

I am trying to read a large csv file line by line in order to find the number of occurences of a string in it.

Here is the code doing it :

```
public int getOffset(File file, String searched) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    int occurences = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String s = scanner.next();
        if (s.indexOf(searched) >= 0) {
            occurences++;
        }
    }
    return occurences;
}
```

However, after it has read the last line of the file, it checks one more time the while condition, and exits with this exception :

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:838)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1347)
at fr.sgcib.cva.mat.MatWriter.getOffset(MatWriter.java:83)
at fr.sgcib.cva.mat.MatWriter.writeFooter(MatWriter.java:71)
at fr.sgcib.cva.mat.NettingNodeHierarchyExtract.getLeNodes(NettingNodeHierarchyExtract.java:65)
at fr.sgcib.cva.mat.Mat.main(Mat.java:55)
```

Why doesn't it detect it's the end of the file ?

Comment: while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {   // checking for next line.           
        String s = scanner.next();  // reading delimited String. Yoou have to be consistent i.e, either use hasNext, scanner.next() ot hasNextLine(), scanner.nextLine()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `String s = scanner.nextLine();` instead of `String s = scanner.next();`

That means that your code would look like this:

```
public int getOffset(File file, String searched) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    int occurences = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String s = scanner.nextLine();
        if (s.indexOf(searched) >= 0) {
            occurences++;
        }
    }
    return occurences;
}
```

In general, when using `Scanner` your `has...` condition needs to match the `next...` data retrieval method

Answer (score 4):

You are checking for the existence of the next line and scanning the next word. Either change the condition in while to `while(scanner.hasNext())` or the scan line to `String s = scanner.nextLine()`.

Try this:

```
public int getOffset(File file, String searched) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    int occurences = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String s = scanner.next();
        if (s.indexOf(searched) >= 0) {
            occurences++;
        }
    }
    return occurences;
}
```

or

```
public int getOffset(File file, String searched) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    int occurences = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String s = scanner.nextLine();
        if (s.indexOf(searched) >= 0) {
            occurences++;
        }
    }
    return occurences;
}
```