# NoSuchElementException in - Java

Tags: java, combobox, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to read data from a text file and then store it to an array. I assume that there is one word per line. I am getting a `NoSuchElementException` here:

```
while (s.hasNextLine()) 
       {
           text = text + s.next() + " ";
       }
```

This is my code:

```
public class ReadNote 
{
   public static void main(String[]args) 
   { 


      String text = readString("CountryList.txt");
      System.out.println(text);

      String[] words = readArray("CountryList.txt");

      for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) 
      {
         System.out.println(words[i]);
      }
}


  public static String readString(String file) 
  {

       String text = "";

       try{
       Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(file));

       while (s.hasNextLine()) 
       {
           text = text + s.next() + " ";
       }

         } catch(FileNotFoundException e) 
           {
              System.out.println("file not found ");
           }
        return text;
   }


  public static String[] readArray(String file) 
  { 
      int ctr = 0;

       try {
       Scanner s1 = new Scanner(new File(file));

       while (s1.hasNextLine()) 
       {
            ctr = ctr+1;
            s1.next();
       }

       String[] words = new String[ctr];
       Scanner s2 = new Scanner(new File(file));

       for ( int i = 0; i < ctr; i++) 
       {
           words [i] = s2.next();
       }

        return words;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { }
        return null;
 }
}
```

Here is the message.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at ReadNote.readString(ReadNote.java:29)
    at ReadNote.main(ReadNote.java:13)
```

Comment: Can you sort out your indentation please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Scanner hasNextLine NoSuchElementException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604794/java-scanner-hasnextline-nosuchelementexception)

Comment: @khelwood Sorry for that, Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific exception you are getting in `readString`:

```
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
  text = text + s.next() + " ";
}
```

You need to either call `s.hasNext()` in the loop guard, or use `s.nextLine()` in the body.

Comment: Thanks i just changed it and it worked. Do you have any idea on how i can store it on a combo box?

Comment: Assuming you mean `JComboBox`, create an instance of it, and then call `addItem`.

Answer (score 0):

There are **2** issues with your code as far as I can tell:

- You forgot to check `hasNextLine()` for your second `Scanner s2`.
  When using `Scanner` you need to check if there is a next line with `hasNextLine()`, and it will return `null` at `EOF`.
- You probably want `s.nextLine()` instead of `s.next()` in your `while` loop since you are checking `while (s1.hasNextLine())`. In general, you *have to* match your `.hasNext...` to your `.next...`.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993377/why-is-hasnext-false-but-hasnextline-is-true).

**You have a single extra newline at the end of your file.**

`hasNextLine()` checks to see if there is another linePattern in the buffer.
`hasNext()` checks to see if there is a parseable token in the buffer, as separated by the scanner's delimiter.

You should modify your code to one of the following

```
while (s.hasNext()) {
    text = text + s.next() + " ";
}

while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    text = text + s.nextLine() + " ";
}
```